# Hibernate Query Deadlock situation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to update multiple entries in the table , and I am getting error of: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Code :

```
**int i= 0;
         for(String name : itemName){
             Item temp = itemDAO.getProductByName(name);  \\ This is select Query
             temp.setQuantity(temp.getQuantity()-Integer.parseInt(itemQuanities[i]));
             itemDAO.updateItemQunatity(temp.getName(), temp.getQuantity()); \\ This is update Query
             i++;
         }**
```

This is leading to deadlock, how could I avoid this ?

Comment: Lock wait timeout and deadlock are [two completely different things](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16564450).  Which do you actually have?

Comment: You must provide us with more information, starting with the complete stack trace, and identify the line in the code that throws the exception.