# Hibernate transaction with mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

On hight loaded service periodically I see a deadlock in DB

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2023-03-06 22:48:18 0x7fa6a24af700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 209985062, ACTIVE 2 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1134110, OS thread handle 140353648719616, query id 13926656547 localhost 127.0.0.1 userdb updating
update element set tags_names_string='XXXXX', genres_names_string='XXXX', description='YYYY' where id=370443
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1313 page no 9937 n bits 120 index PRIMARY of table user.element trx id 209985062 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 209985053, ACTIVE 3 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
551 lock struct(s), heap size 90320, 985 row lock(s), undo log entries 545
MySQL thread id 1134109, OS thread handle 140353664120576, query id 13926657948 localhost 127.0.0.1 userdb updating
update element set last_update='2023-03-06 22:48:15.912' where id=370443
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 1313 page no 9937 n bits 120 index PRIMARY of table user.element trx id 209985053 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1313 page no 9937 n bits 120 index PRIMARY of table user.element trx id 209985053 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

It happens if two consecutive updates modify the same row. Every update touching a single record by one query with filtering by pk

The magic is that I have a synchronization in the java code for the table updates.

I've been trying to fix a problem for a long time. Because of retry no lost of data happens, but curiosity does not allow me to leave this problem unsolved.

```
SpringSefviceClass (singleton):

def synchronized updateElement(ElementMessage msg) {
  Element.withNewTransaction {
    def e = Element.get(e.id)
    e.xxx= msg.xxx
    ... 
    e.save(flush: true)
  }
  sleep(400)
}
```

`sleep` added to be sure that all DB transaction activity finished. That decreases the amount of errors, but it happens anyway. With sleep(10000) I see no more errors in the log, but that is too slow for the service.

In my understanding, DB transactions have to be finished before ending a transaction in java code. In my code before *sleep* line execution. But by the error I see, that it's not finished even after sleep! I'm sure, only one thread executing method at one time (have checked by logging)

`dynamicUpdate` option of hibernate used (in the update query only changed the field mentioned). No changes on indexed columns.

- Table contains 500k records.
- 5.7.35-38-log Percona Server
- java 11
- spring 5.3.25
- hibernate 5.6.11.Final
- Around 40Gb of memory allocated by DB.  Fast SSD used.   Server usually 40% busy with 0.1-1% IO CPU time. load average: 8.00, 9.70, 9.36 on 12 cores

Any ideas?

### Update

The main question, why after commiting transaction mysql still doing something with records and deadclock happance

Comment: What exactly *is* the problem you are trying to solve? Deadlocks are natural at certain isolation levels, and you said yourself there are transactions touching the same rows, so there *are* race conditions. What did you expect to happen instead? If you don't care which update wins and/or the update doesn't care about stale reads, perhaps you should simply pick a less strict isolation level. Otherwise it's a *good thing* conflicts are getting detected

Comment: @crizzis The problem in deadlock between two sequencial transactions. They are executed in one thread. And  where is a sleep for 400ms between transactions. Anyway I have a deadlock on heawy load

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into the following possible problems:

- your code does not close the DB connection after the transaction completes
- for whatever other reason you're [hitting the `lock_wait_timeout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563843/deadlock-vs-lockwait-timeout-on-mysql) - you could lower that instead of introducing the sleep timeout

In general, having `sleep` in your code in order to prevent deadlocks is poor design.

In case you need to do multiple `UPDATE`s on the same record in that short period of time, I would suggest caching the changes and performing them together.

Comment: In query log I see transaction commit in same time with ending transaction in the code.

Comment: OK - but do you close the DB connection right after the transaction completes? Locks are granted on connection level, not transaction level.

Comment: I'm using db pool. I'm not sure about looks by connection. Could you provide any details?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of leaving deadlock detection up to the DB to discover, you can manage it yourself and remove the sleep() entirely. This is threadsafe. You can further improve it by doing bulk updates, if you can make sure the IDs are unique.

Something like this:

```
// Define a concurrent set to store updating IDs
ConcurrentSet<Long> updatingIds = new ConcurrentHashSet<>()
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ElementMessage> pendingUpdates = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>()

...

def updateElement(ElementMessage msg) {
    // Get the ID of the element being updated
    Long elementId = msg.elementId
    
    if (updatingIds.contains(elementId)) {
        // If the elementId is already being updated, enqueue the msg
        pendingUpdates.add(msg)
        return // Return without processing this update further
    }
    
    updatingIds.add(elementId)
    
    Element.withNewTransaction {
        try {
            def e = Element.get(elementId)
            e.xxx = msg.xxx
            // ...
            e.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exceptions
        } finally {
            updatingIds.remove(elementId)
            
            // Process pending updates
            ElementMessage pendingMsg
            while ((pendingMsg = pendingUpdates.poll()) != null) {
                updateElement(pendingMsg)
            }
        }
    }
}
```